# Looped in same data on second if statement

Tags: python

I'm trying to pass a list through a nested if series. Each if statement calls a separate function. The first if statement iterates through the file (list) completely, but after the number first passes through the first if statement, that number gets repeated through the 2nd statement infinitely until the first statement is done.

Ex: First few numbers from the list are:

```
['8812', '1816', '9726', '3463']
```

**The first if statement goes through the whole list, but the second statement checks `'8812'` for all 4 runs of the first statement and never runs to the other numbers.**

Any idea what's going on here:

```
total = 0
counter = 0
for c in rumbers:
    if (isHarshad(int(c)) == True):
        #print(int(c))
        total = total + int(c)
        if (isSiete(int(c)) == True):
            print(c)
            #ofile = open(HarshOut.txt, 'w')
            #ofile.close()
    else:
        #print(c, " is false - main")
```

---

**Functions**

```
def isHarshad (number):

    #conversion to iterable list
    numberlist = list(str(number))
    digittotal = 0

    #iterate through the list
    for iterate in numberlist:
        digittotal += int(iterate)

      #Will the numbers be divisible?
    if (number % digittotal == 0):
        return True
    else:
        return False

#isSiete Function declaration
def isSiete(number):
    for number in rumbers:
        if(number[-2] == '7'):
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

---

**Print Statements:**

```
7440  is false - main
isSiete number is:  8812
3110  is false - main
isSiete number is:  8812
5202  is false - main
isSiete number is:  8812
9288  is false - main
isSiete number is:  8812
7770  is false - main
isSiete number is:  8812
1170  is false - main
isSiete number is:  8812
4  is false - main
```

---

**Should Happen?**

myList ['8812', '1816', '9276', '3463']

Is 8812 a Harshad number?

1. If yes, check to see if the digit in the 10's place is a 7 using isSiete.
2. If no, move on to the next item in the list.

At the end of the parameters (or on failure).

1. Start over using the next number.

---

```
7440  is false - main
isSiete number is:  7440
3110  is false - main
isSiete number is:  3110
5202  is false - main
isSiete number is:  5202  
9288  is false - main
isSiete number is:  9288  
7770  is false - main
isSiete number is:  7770
1170  is false - main
isSiete number is:  1170
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: @James see update for clarity.

Comment: @Jonathan Can you show the `isHarshad` and `isSiete` functions?

Comment: That's weird.  Could you share the output of those `print` statements?

Comment: Why are you overriding the `number` parameter in `isSiete`?

Comment: @gommb You mean in the for statement?

Comment: Yes the for statement in `isSiete` is overriding the `number` parameter

Comment: @gommb If I choose a random iterator then I get   'if(number[-2] == '7'):
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable'

Comment: @wyatt added above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def is_harshad(n):
    total = sum(int(d) for d in str(n))
    return n % total == 0

def isSiete(number):
    return str(number)[-2] == '7'

total = 0
for c in numbers:
    if is_harshad(int(c)):
        #print(int(c))
        total = total + int(c)
        if isSiete(int(c)):
            print(c)
            #ofile = open(HarshOut.txt, 'w')
            #ofile.close()
    else:
        print(c, " is false - main")
```

Comment: Looks like isSiete was broken. With that one fix, it's working fine. Thanks.

Comment: any idea why I would be throwing a string out of bounds for isSiete?

Comment: It would be out of bounds if the number is one digit, since it is checking the 10's place and single digit numbers don't have 10's places.